# How do I add custom hierarchical keybindings?

Tags: key-bindings

I am looking for a compact way to store a lot of shortcut key bindings. This is my current idea, for which I'm looking for help how to add this into my Emacs config:

I would like to make `F9` "my" key, that opens up a hierarchical menu of (global) key bindings.

When pressing `F9`, I'd like a submenu to open that shows e.g.:

```
o - org-mode submenu
a - show org-mode agenda
w - org-wiki submenu
b - org-brain submenu
```

If I press `F9-a`, I'd like to directly execute the `M-x org-agenda` command.

But by pressing `F9-w`, I get a new submenu opened that e.g. shows this:

```
# Org-wiki submenu
i - Show Wiki index
n - Add new Wiki page
```

If my final keystroke sequence is `F9-w-i`, I want the command `M-x org-wiki-index` executed.

- Does something like this exist already?
- Is there a better solution?
- If no, how would I add something like this in my emacs config?

/Edit: I think what I want is to write my custom version of the `M-x org-agenda` command.

Comment: Have you looked at hydra? https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra and available from melpa?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need! I wasn't aware of this package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @icarus suggested, hydra is the way to go here. Check out my solution that is similar to what you want here: https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax/blob/master/scimax-hydra.el

there are submenus of keys that open new hydras. I have mine bound to f12, and then remapped caps lock to be f12. It is convenient for me.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually using it for org-ref now, so double-thanks :) Then org-wiki and/or org-brain.

Answer (score 2):

If you install and enable [which-key](https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key) then Emacs will do that (albeit with more compact formatting) for *every* prefix binding, including your custom ones.